# Как исправить ошибку на ОС Windows: ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found, please install one?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, ffmpeg

Я пытаюсь конвертировать видео `.webm` в `mp3`, но получаю ошибку -  `ffprobe/avprobe and ffmpeg/avconv not found, please install one.` В интернете есть решение этой проблемы, но делается это или на Linux или на macOS. Вопрос заключается в следующем - как сделать так же, чтобы можно было конвертировать аудио, но только на OC Windows? Я использую Python 3.7.4, Windows 10.
Я пытался установить пакеты `pip install ffmpeg` и `pip install ffprobe` но это ничего не дало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалось все намного проще. Достаточно скачать сборку `ffmpeg` для Вашего ПК с сайта  https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/.

После распаковки zip-архива нужно перейти в папку `/bin` и скопировать из неё 3 файла: `ffmpeg.exe`, `ffplay.exe` и `ffprobe.exe` и переместить по адресу: `C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\YourVersionPython\Scripts`.

Готово :)